# What does the getSerie method of SysDictTable return in AX?

Tags: msdn, dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

The SysDatabaseLog wizard seems to group the tables that are available for auditing by the result of this method call. MSDN has **no** documentation on this method.

I need to know what it is returning so I can have a chance of putting some user tables into the wizard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It returns the *label* of the *topmost* parent security key.

E.g. the security key of `PriceDiscTable` is `BasicTables`, the parent security key of `BasicTables` is `Basic` - it doesn't have a parent, hence its label (`Basic` in English, `Basis` in Danish, etc.) will be returned.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to clarify that!

Answer (score 0):

Okay the code is actually available in AX. It returns the name of the Security Key.